# GridViewColumn bind content to method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Simplified Student class

```
public class StudentListModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public double CountPoints(Guid courseId)
    {
        var studentRepo = new StudentRepository();
        var student = studentRepo.FindById(this.Id);
        var evals = student.Evaluations.Where(e => e.Course.Id == courseId).ToList();

        return evals.Sum(eval => eval.ObtainedPoints);
    }
}
```

Simplified View

```
<UserControl
DataContext="{Binding CourseDetailViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

...

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Detail.Students, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="60"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Login} />
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" x:Name="Points" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

...

</UserControl>
```

DataContext of the View

```
public class CourseDetailViewModel
{
    private CourseDetailModel _detail;
    public CourseDetailModel Detail
    {
        get { return _detail; }
    }
}
```

CourseDetailModel:
The *courseId* parameter for method *StudentListModel.CountPoints()* comes from here.

```
public class CourseDetailModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

In column *Points* I want to display data obtained from method *CountPoints()*. Is there any way how to do that and pass parameter to this method?

Comment: Not exactly; you can write a value converter, though. And it's possible you don't really need to pass a parameter. Where is the `courseId` parameter coming from?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I made the question more specific, so you can see where `courseId` parameter comes from.

Comment: OK, the listview items are whatever's in `Detail.Students`. That's a collection of `StudentListModel`. So... same `courseId` for everybody in the listview? Like, this is a list of everybody's grade in Rocks for Jocks or Social Justice Topics in Geomorphology or something?

Comment: And it's a property of the same `Detail` object as `Students` is? Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the `courseId` is the same for all the students in the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

What you can do is write a value converter that calls it for you. Since we need to bind more than one value (the `StudentListModel` we're calling the method on, and also the parameter for the method), we'll have to use a multi-value converter with a multibinding.

```
public class CountStudentCoursePointsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var studentModel = (StudentListModel)values[0];
        var courseId = (Guid)values[1];

        return studentModel.CountPoints(courseId); 
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //  Can't convert back, don't try. 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<!-- 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged tells the binding when to update the viewmodel 
property. Well, a ListView cannot ever give your viewmodel a new collection of items,
so don't bother giving it that flag. 
-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Detail.Students}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:CountStudentCoursePointsConverter
            x:Key="CoursePointsConverter"
            />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="60"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Login}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" x:Name="Points">
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CoursePointsConverter}">
                            <!-- 
                            No path gives us the row item itself, an instance of 
                            StudentListModel.
                            -->
                            <Binding />
                            <!-- 
                            The parent viewmodel is the DataContext of our ancestor 
                            control, the ListView. That's a CourseDetailViewModel. 
                            So go there with RelativeSource, get its Detail property,
                            and grab the Id.
                            -->
                            <Binding
                                Path="DataContext.Detail.Id"
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"
                                />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

You can also drop that `ToList()` call from `CountPoints()`; there's no need to construct a List there. If `StudentRepository` implements `IDisposable`, you'll want to put that in a `using` block as well.

```
    public double CountPoints(Guid courseId)
    {
        var studentRepo = new StudentRepository();
        var student = studentRepo.FindById(this.Id);

        return 
            student.Evaluations
            .Where(e => e.Course.Id == courseId)
            .Sum(eval => eval.ObtainedPoints);
    }
```

**On the whole, however**, it might be best to populate the listview from a query that calculates the points in SQL, or with LINQ to SQL. That would be my preference. I don't like to optimize prematurely, but I wonder what overhead you'll have with all these `StudentRepository` queries.

Comment: This code works flawlessly, so many thanks to you. The only problem is that  (correctly) calculated points are not shown in the column and column stays blank. Even if I return hardcoded value from converter...

Comment: @SamoPoláček That's hardly flawless! Did you put a breakpoint in the converter Convert method and confirm it's not throwing an exception?

Comment: @SamoPoláček I wouldn't expect that to be necessary. Hmm.